# Spring Integration: How does RendezvousChannel work?

Tags: spring

I haven't been able to find any examples of how the RendezvousChannel works in Spring Integration. Does anyone know of any resources?

I've read that RendezvousChannel is useful for adapting request/response clients to the asynchronous messaging in Spring Integration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RendezvousChannel` extends `QueueChannel` and exhibits the same behaviour:

- Reading from the channel blocks until either a message is available or a timeout occurs.
- Writing to the channel blocks until the queue's capacity permits another message or a timeout occurs.

Internally however, `RendezvousChannel` uses a capacity of **0** in conjunction with a [`SynchronousQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html). Therefore, senders will block until receivers have finished, well, receiving and vice versa, basically establishing synchronous communication.

As for examples, I don't think there are any yet.

If you want to get an impression of how `RendezvousChannel` can be used as temporary reply channel for implementing request/reply scenarios (as hinted at in the [reference documentation spring channel-implementations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-implementations), section 4.1.2), have a look at the source code of the `sendAndReceive` method of [`MessageChannelTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-template). That one uses `PollableChannel` implementation internally, but the pattern could be easily transfered `RendezvousChannel`.